# How to prove that $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is a UFD

Tags: commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k$ be a field.
$k[x,y]$ is a UFD by the following known argument taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain):
"If $R$ is a UFD, then so is $R[X]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $R$. Unless $R$ is a field, $R[X]$ is not a principal ideal domain. By induction, a polynomial ring in any number of variables over any UFD (and in particular over a field) is a UFD".

**(1)** It seems that $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is a UFD, isn't it?
Is the proof based on the result that $k[x,y]$ is a UFD? (probably yes?)

**(2)** Can one find all irreducible=prime elements of $k[x,x^{-1},y]$?
("In UFDs, every irreducible element is prime").

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The ring of Laurent polynomials $R=k[x,x^{-1}]=\bigl(k[x]\bigr)_{x}$, and a ring of fractions of a U.F.D. is a U.F.D., so $k[x,x^{-1},y]=R[y]$ is a U.F.D.
2. You can find the irreducible elements of $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ inasmuch as you can find those of $k[x,y]$. They're the same as the irreducible elements in $k[x,y]$ except $x$, which becomes a unit in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$. Which elements in $k[x,y]$ are irreducible depends on the base field.

Comment: Thank you. Please, could you elaborate on (2)?

Comment: I do not know which answer to accept. I like (1) of the first answer and (2) of the second answer..

Comment: Does not really matter. I would give it to Bernard for pointing out the mistake which led to my (1) then.

Comment: Fine, but only after he will slightly explain (2).

Comment: I just meant that, for instance, $x^2+y^2$ is irreducible if $k=\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf Q or \mathbf F_3$, and it can be factorised if $k=\mathbf C$ or $\mathbf F_5$. Furthermore, there are irreducible polynomials in two indeterminates of any degree.

Answer (score 1):

1) Localization of a UFD is again a UFD (at least if you are not inverting $0$). Maybe you can try to prove that.

2) Is there any condition on $k$?

Comment: Oh you are right! I was being careless.

Comment: I changed my argument.

Comment: @ThorWittich, I think that (1) is true (I have seen the argument about localization, but somehow forgot it). Thank you.

Comment: @ThorWittich: Fine! (b.t.w., I didn't downvote your answer).

Comment: Yes. This is true in contrast to my first argument.

Comment: (I also didn't downvoted your answer). I am trying to understand (2).

Comment: @Bernard Even if it was you, I do not really mind. Your note was important.

Comment: @user237522 Bernard's answer gives more details on that.